# Pandas dataframe not properly sorted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have several excel data files, each one referring to a different timing (i.e. 0h, 24h, 48h, ...), and the columns with the data of interest are named: 'Product' and 'Value'.
I have concatenated those files by using the following:

```
result = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file) for file in filenames], keys=t_list, names=['t'])
```

where filenames is a list containing the excel files, t_list is a list containing the timings, 't' is the name of the newly created column with the timings.
So far so good, and I get a new dataframe with the following structure:

Concatenated Dataframe:
[image: concatenated dataframe]

But then, if I sort with the following:

```
result['Product'].astype(str)
result.sort_values('Product', ascending=True)
```

I found the correct order for some items, but not for others. Indeed, I get something like the following:

Dataframe not properly sorted:
[image: dataframe not properly sorted]

Can someone shed a light on this?

Comment: you need to specify the columns for the sort you're dealing with unstructured data with no proper index.

Comment: Thanks a lot Manakin, but the answer by Daweo (see below) solved this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can someone shed a light on this?*

Default sorting algorithm of [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) is not stable, therefore order of elements with equal `Product` might be different than before sorting. To avoid that you might elect to use `kind="mergesort"` in `sort_values`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `'Products'`, pass a list of the columns you want to sort by.

If you want to sort by 'Product' and then by 'Value', it looks like this:

```
result.sort_values(['Product', 'Value'], ascending=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I try to sort by 'Product' and 't' (this is what I need), then I get the following error message: ValueError: No axis named t for object type DataFrame